# Does anyone have any sample code or suggestions to help me to interface my 100 pin uc3a1512to a device via RS-485?

Tags: atmel, rs485

I am attempting to connect and control a device which only accepts RS-485 input. I wish to communicate to this device via my existing UC3A1512. Does anyone have any existing source code or examples that may help me to create this interface?

I need a method of outputting date via RS-485 format.

I do not need to establish round trip communication, I simply need the ability to send commands to the device.

I have looked at Atmel's website and also on AVRFreaks and I see nothing of value to my project.

Any help is welcomed and appreciated!

I originally posted this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033256/does-anyone-have-any-sample-code-or-suggestions-to-help-me-to-interface-my-100-pi) before I knew of [electronics.stackexchange.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put a RS-485 transceiver on your USART. Maybe a TI SN65HVD11, looks like it works with 3.3V IO.

As you you need to transmit, any sample that writes out the USART in asynchronous  mode will do.

As you don't mention having to share a RS-485 bus, tie the TX enable on on the transceiver.

That way RS-232 example code will work for you.

Comment: This simple logic chip looks like it will do the trick.  I appreciate your solution.  I will try this and I will let you know how it works out.  I also like the size as size truly matters in micro-controller development.

Comment: This is a nice chip, small footprint.  I like that its simple in that its just a logic and amplifier together.  Good answer.

Comment: And for the software side, look in the excellent AVR32 Software Framework available from Atmel which has drivers and examples for the USARTs.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about the RS-485 physical connection or the data protocol that you have to use?  From the phrasing of the question I will assume that it is the former.

RS-485 specifies the signal levels and number of wires used to send the data together with the maximum transmission distances for the various data rates used, in much the same way as RS-232.  All that you need to do, from a physical point of view, is to replace any RS-232 driver with an RS-485 transceiver.  These are available from many suppliers (Maxim, TI, ON-semi...)  As you say you only have to transmit to the remote device, you can just leave the receive side open and use 3 wires to connect to the remote device (TxA, TxB and Gnd).

The commands sent to the remote device are defined in its protocol spec and will be sent in exactly the same way as on any other async serial interface.

Answer (score 1):

3 led on/off by one swoft switch to 8051 in asm51 code.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Try the MAX485 or MAX483 from Maxim IC: http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/1111
Very cheap and easy to use. Plus they can send data up to 4000 feet.

Here's someone's tutorial on using them with Arduino: 
http://pskillenrules.blogspot.com/2009/08/arduino-and-rs485.html

Comment: I've written a blog post about these chips: http://www.tmatthew.net/blog/long_distance_serial